# 'lambda_function': No module named 'ask_sdk_core'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-lambda-layers

Hope you are doing well :)

I pip installed all the external libs into a folder. Zipped the installed libs. Uploaded it to lambda's layers. However, I ended up with such an error. Does anyone know why? let me know if there is any other useful info for me to provide.[image]

Here's my directory tree view of the installed libs:

```
├───ask_sdk_core
│   ├───dispatch_components
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───utils
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───view_resolvers
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───ask_sdk_core-1.14.0.dist-info
├───ask_sdk_model
│   ├───canfulfill
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───dialog
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───dynamic_endpoints
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───er
│   │   ├───dynamic
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───events
│   │   ├───skillevents
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───interfaces
│   │   ├───alexa
│   │   │   ├───comms
│   │   │   │   ├───messagingcontroller
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───presentation
│   │   │   │   ├───apl
│   │   │   │   │   ├───listoperations
│   │   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   ├───apla
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   ├───aplt
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   ├───html
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───amazonpay
│   │   │   ├───model
│   │   │   │   ├───request
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   ├───response
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   ├───v1
│   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───request
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───response
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───v1
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───audioplayer
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───automotive
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───connections
│   │   │   ├───entities
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───requests
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───v1
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───conversations
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───custom_interface_controller
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───display
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───gadget_controller
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───game_engine
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───geolocation
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───messaging
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───monetization
│   │   │   ├───v1
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───navigation
│   │   │   ├───assistance
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───playbackcontroller
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───system
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───tasks
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───videoapp
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───viewport
│   │   │   ├───apl
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───aplt
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───size
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   ├───video
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───services
│   │   ├───device_address
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───directive
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───endpoint_enumeration
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───gadget_controller
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───game_engine
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───list_management
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───lwa
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───monetization
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───proactive_events
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───reminder_management
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───skill_messaging
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───timer_management
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───ups
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───slu
│   │   ├───entityresolution
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───ui
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───ask_sdk_model-1.24.0.dist-info
├───ask_sdk_runtime
│   ├───dispatch_components
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───view_resolvers
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───ask_sdk_runtime-1.14.0.dist-info
├───bin
├───cachetools
│   └───__pycache__
├───cachetools-4.1.1.dist-info
├───certifi
│   └───__pycache__
├───certifi-2020.6.20.dist-info
├───chardet
│   ├───cli
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───chardet-3.0.4.dist-info
├───click
│   └───__pycache__
├───click-7.1.2.dist-info
├───dateutil
│   ├───parser
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───tz
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───zoneinfo
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───flask
│   ├───json
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───Flask-1.1.2.dist-info
├───google
│   ├───api
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───api_core
│   │   ├───future
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───gapic_v1
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───operations_v1
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───auth
│   │   ├───compute_engine
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───crypt
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───transport
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───logging
│   │   └───type
│   │       └───__pycache__
│   ├───longrunning
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───oauth2
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───protobuf
│   │   ├───compiler
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───internal
│   │   │   ├───import_test_package
│   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───pyext
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───util
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───rpc
│   │   ├───context
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───type
│       └───__pycache__
├───googleapis_common_protos-1.52.0.dist-info
├───google_api_core-1.22.0.dist-info
├───google_auth-1.20.0.dist-info
├───idna
│   └───__pycache__
├───idna-2.10.dist-info
├───itsdangerous
│   └───__pycache__
├───itsdangerous-1.1.0.dist-info
├───jinja2
│   └───__pycache__
├───Jinja2-2.11.2.dist-info
├───markupsafe
│   └───__pycache__
├───MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info
├───pkg_resources
│   ├───extern
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───_vendor
│   │   ├───packaging
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───protobuf-3.12.4.dist-info
├───pyasn1
│   ├───codec
│   │   ├───ber
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───cer
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───der
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───native
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───compat
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───type
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───pyasn1-0.4.8.dist-info
├───pyasn1_modules
│   └───__pycache__
├───pyasn1_modules-0.2.8.dist-info
├───python_dateutil-2.8.1.dist-info
├───pytz
│   ├───zoneinfo
│   │   ├───Africa
│   │   ├───America
│   │   │   ├───Argentina
│   │   │   ├───Indiana
│   │   │   ├───Kentucky
│   │   │   └───North_Dakota
│   │   ├───Canada
│   │   └───US
│   └───__pycache__
├───pytz-2020.1.dist-info
├───requests
│   └───__pycache__
├───requests-2.24.0.dist-info
├───rsa
│   └───__pycache__
├───rsa-4.6.dist-info
├───setuptools
│   ├───command
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───extern
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───_distutils
│   │   ├───command
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───_vendor
│   │   ├───packaging
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───setuptools-49.2.0.dist-info
├───six-1.15.0.dist-info
├───urllib3
│   ├───contrib
│   │   ├───_securetransport
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───packages
│   │   ├───backports
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───ssl_match_hostname
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───util
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───urllib3-1.25.10.dist-info
├───werkzeug
│   ├───debug
│   │   ├───shared
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───middleware
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───wrappers
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───Werkzeug-1.0.1.dist-info
└───__pycache__
```

Comment: yep, please describe in detail how you build your layers. If you can provide a directory tree view, that would be perfect.

Comment: @jellycsc I did. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, what's the parent of `ask_sdk_core`?

Comment: @jellycsc The parent is a folder called zip. However, when I uploaded the libs files to layers, I didn't zip the parent folder but zipped all the lib files within the parent folder. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I think I figured out where the problem is from your last comment. According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) doc,

> To include libraries in a layer, place them in one of the folders supported by your runtime, or modify that path variable for your language.

and for Python, the directory that all libraries should reside in is `python` (or `python/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages` which is not very useful here).

So to fix the issue you are having here, just

1. Rename the `zip` folder to `python`
2. Zip the `python` itself

Comment: You are a genuis! Thank you so much for looking it up :))

Comment: If my answer helps, please consider accepting my answer :) Thanks @DanielDehleh

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did press it. Thanks once again :)